# How to expand HugSQL parameter into multiple like statements

Tags: clojure, hugsql

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

`(get-lists ["free" "food"])` ->

```
Select name 
From Lists
Where name like '%free%' and name like '%food%'
```

I have tried:

```
-- :name get-lists :? :*
Select id, name
from Lists
where
--~ (clojure.string/join "" (interpose " AND " (map #(str "name LIKE '%" % "%'") :sKeyWords)))
```

But of course that does not work. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 2):

Figured out answer. Putting here for anyone else who might need it.

```
-- :name get-lists :? :*
Select id, name
from Lists
--~ (str "WHERE " 
        (clojure.string/join " AND " (map #(str "name LIKE '%" % "%'") 
          (:key-words params))))
```

Comment: `(clojure.string/join "" (interpose " AND " [1 2 3]))` is `(clojure.string/join " AND " [1 2 3])`

Answer (score 2):

To form a query you can also use [clojure.pprint/cl-format](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.pprint/cl-format) from clojure's standard lib, which is quite powerful and concise:

```
user> (require '[clojure.pprint :refer [cl-format]])

user> (cl-format nil "WHERE~{ name LIKE '%~a%' ~^AND~}" 
                 ["me" "you" "somebody"])
;;=> "WHERE name LIKE '%me%' AND name LIKE '%you%' AND name LIKE '%somebody%' "
```

Comment: That is powerful! and quite terse. A bit of a mystery without learning the language though :)